# Cleaner Way to Sort and Order a Vector of Maps in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I have a vector of maps wherein I need to remove the maps where the value of the name key is a duplicate, keeping the one that has the highest value of age. I have a solution but I don't think it looks clean. Is there a better way to do it without breaking it up into multiple functions?

Here is my data:

```
(def my-maps
    [{:name "jess", :age 32} 
     {:name "ruxpin", :age 4} 
     {:name "jess", :age 35} 
     {:name "aero", :age 33} 
     {:name "banner", :age 4}])
```

Here is my solution:

```
(map first (vals (group-by :name (reverse (sort-by :name my-maps)))))
```

Result:

```
({:name "ruxpin", :age 4} {:name "jess", :age 35} {:name "banner", :age 4} {:name "aero", :age 33})
```

Comment: That is not a vector of sets. A set is represented as #{} in Clojure, and is not an associative key/value structure. You have a vector of maps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

another way is the combination of `group-by` and `max-key`. The advantage of this method is that you don't need to sort your collection, and `sort` in turn has an impact on performance and if it can be avoided it should be.

```
(for [[_ vs] (group-by :name my-maps)]
  (apply max-key :age vs))

;;=> ({:name "jess", :age 35} 
;;    {:name "ruxpin", :age 4} 
;;    {:name "aero", :age 33} 
;;    {:name "banner", :age 4})
```

Answer (score 2):

short version

```
(->> my-set
     (sort-by (juxt :name :age) #(compare %2 %1)) ; sort-by :name, :age in reverse order
     (partition-by :name)
     (map first))
```

a transducer version

```
(def xf (comp (partition-by :name) (map first)))
(->> my-set
     (sort-by (juxt :name :age) #(compare %2 %1))
     (into [] xf))
```

for large dataset, the transducer should be better

Answer (score 1):

Your original solution was actually broken unfortunately. It just seemed to work because of the order you had the data in `my-set` in. Note how you never actually sort by age, so you can never guarantee what order the ages are in.

I solved this with another call to `map`:

```
(->> my-set (group-by :name) 
            (vals)

            ; Sort by age each list that group-by returns
            (map #(sort-by :age %)) 

            (map last)) ; This could also happen in the above map
```

Note how I'm sorting each `:name` group by `:age`, *then* I take the last of each grouping.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Jessie No problem. I would advise against accepting my answer right away though. There are many talented Clojurists on SO; someone may give you a better answer later. And note the terminology changes that Taylor is suggesting. You say you're using Sets, but you don't have any in the code you posted. You have maps (`{}`), not sets (`#{}`).

Comment: Ok haha. I will wait a little while.

Comment: @JessieRichardson There. After some playing around, it appears to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it a little differently, using the `max` function instead of sorting:

```
(def my-maps
  [{:name "jess", :age 32}
   {:name "ruxpin", :age 4}
   {:name "jess", :age 35}
   {:name "aero", :age 33}
   {:name "banner", :age 4}])

(dotest
  (let [grouped-data  (group-by :name my-maps)
        name-age-maps (for [[name map-list] grouped-data]
                        (let [max-age      (apply max
                                             (map :age map-list))
                              name-age-map {name max-age}]
                          name-age-map))
        final-result  (reduce into {} name-age-maps)]
    final-result))
```

with results:

```
grouped-data => 
{"jess" [{:name "jess", :age 32} {:name "jess", :age 35}],
 "ruxpin" [{:name "ruxpin", :age 4}],
 "aero" [{:name "aero", :age 33}],
 "banner" [{:name "banner", :age 4}]}

name-age-maps => 
({"jess" 35} {"ruxpin" 4} {"aero" 33} {"banner" 4})

final-result => 
{"jess" 35, "ruxpin" 4, "aero" 33, "banner" 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare by vector fields with different weight and data type (size has more weight), size is descending, name is ascending:

```
(def some-vector [{:name "head" :size 3}
                            {:name "mouth" :size 1}
                            {:name "nose" :size 1}
                            {:name "neck" :size 2}
                            {:name "chest" :size 10}
                            {:name "back" :size 10}
                            {:name "abdomen" :size 6}
                            ])
(->> (some-vector)
  (sort #(compare (str (format "%3d" (:size %2)) (:name %1))
                  (str (format "%3d" (:size %1)) (:name %2))
  )))
```